# How to just save tensor not models in Tensorflow2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have learned Tensorflow2 for several months but I meet some difficulty.For example,I create one tensor like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
v=tf.random.normal((20,30,40))
```

Now I just want to save tensor v into suitable file.Actually speaking ,v is created from .nc data.I use packages "netCDF4" to read it and select some variables,whose dimensions are (time,lon,lat),to concat them into v with dimensions of (time,lon,lat,var_num).

But v's size is large (for example,(1000,224,224,5)).So I need to save v in case of reading netcdf for many times. I search some questions but little can help me because they are either about saving variables in tf1.X or saving models(or variables in models) in tf 2.

So I come here and seek handsome persons's help.Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the [saved model format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) to store a single `tf.Variable`

You would just capture `v` in a `tf.Variable` then pass that to `tf.saved_model.save`.

Maybe something like this:

```py
v=tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((20,30,40)))
tf.saved_model.save(v, '/path/to/my_var')
```

then to load again from the saved version:

```py
v_from_file = tf.saved_model.load('/path/to/my_var')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.With your methods I have solve my problem!
Maybe before it's my fault idea that save_model is only used in models~

Comment: @janeasefor my pleasure. Glad it's solved. :-) If my solution helped maybe you would consider accepting and/or upvoting it

Comment: Ok!Now my reputation is less than 15.One day when  reaching the threshold I will come back to vote your answer.

Comment: Note: This only works in eager mode. Not in graph mode inside a traced @tf.function.